# Django tastypie save reverse GenericForeignKeyField

Tags: django, tastypie, generic-foreign-key

Django Tastypie can save related objects even with reverse relationship.

But is it able for Django Tastypie to save reverse relationship of GenericForeignKeyField?

My resources (not full, but the important only),

```
class AreaResource(ModelResource):
    tripl3user = fields.ManyToManyField(
        'tripl3sales.api.resources.area.Tripl3UserResource',
        'tripl3user',
        related_name='area',
        full=True
    )

class Tripl3UserResource(ModelResource):
    content_type = fields.ForeignKey(
        'tripl3sales.api.resources.contenttype.ContentTypeResource',
        'content_type'
    )
    content_object = GenericForeignKeyField({
        Area : AreaResource
        }, 'content_object')
```

My `models.py`,

```
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    tripl3user = generic.GenericRelation('Tripl3User')

class Tripl3User(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Is it possible to save reverse relationship of generic foreign key? If so, then how to do it? What does the data look like?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer.

In a resource that has `content_type` and `object_id`, there is no need to declare `content_type` because `content_object` is enough. And for related_name, instead of using `area`, we use `content_object`.

So, my **resources.py** should be,

```
class AreaResource(ModelResource):
    tripl3user = fields.ManyToManyField(
        'tripl3sales.api.resources.area.Tripl3UserResource',
        'tripl3user',
        related_name='content_object',
        full=True
    )

class Tripl3UserResource(ModelResource):
    content_object = GenericForeignKeyField({
        Area : AreaResource
    }, 'content_object')
```

Hope this will help others.